# Heroes of the storm Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

Got an Alpha key for Heroes of the storm today and I've installed it on my Ubuntu computer. The thing is, I cannot get it to launch. Installation went perfectly, but I cannot actually get the game to run (I get the standard Blizzard error). On the WINE page for the game it claims it will run without any problems, even though some had issues while in the game.

I run `wine-1.7.33`. I have no special settings applied. Anyone know something I could try? I know Linux isn't supported and it's an Technical Alpha but still, people claim it works fine on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to game settings under the options menu and mark "Launch 32-bit client (Instead of 64-bit)". It seems the 64 bit one fails at the gate, at least for me.